# What do PhD committees focus on when examining the CV of a graduate applying for a PhD?

Tags: phd

In evaluating a Ph.D. candidate's application, what is the pivotal element that selection committees seek and immediately disregard the application if it's absent from the applicant's CV/Resume?

Comment: Why do you believe there is a "pivotal element" in a complex decision process? This applies to your previous question about post-docs as well. Or, any other application process, be it for a job or club membership or mortgage or ...

Comment: A "lack of university degree" is possibly the only answer, and I would not put my hand in the fire for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single element that will kill your application. I have friends, professors in the Ivies and other R1s, who failed courses in their respective disciplines as undergrads, who got terrible GREs scores when applying to grad school, and who have no social skills to do well in an interview. You name one criterion, and I'll tell you an example of a successful PhD despite not meeting that criterion.

What makes a successful PhD student has been answered elsewhere, and the usual criteria grad schools use in admissions has been discussed ad nauseam.

Worry less about your chances of admission, and more about if grad school is the best way to your career goals, in the context of the current employment market for academics.